# Windows 11 emoji panel search box displays random characters when I type in a query

Tags: windows-11, emoji-keyboard

When typing in the search box of the Windows 11 emoji picker, all I see are random characters. And it's not even consistent - sometimes the letter `a` might be replaced with `r`, sometimes `v`, you get the picture. This is on a brand new ASUS Zenbook laptop. Other than Microsoft Office 365, I haven't installed anything on it yet. I typed in `thumb` here to look for the `thumbs up` emoji, this is what is displayed:

[image: searching for thumb]

OS: Windows 11 Pro Version 22H2 Installed on ‎7/‎4/‎2023 OS build 22621.2283 Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22662.1000.0

Comment: What build of Windows 11 are you running?

Comment: Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on ‎7/‎4/‎2023
OS build 22621.2283
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22662.1000.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It was ESET Internet Security's Secure All Browsers feature that was doing it. I turned that feature off and all is working normally again.

ESET Browser protection
[image]

Comment: I only needed to disable the "Secured browser => Keyboard protection" option. PS: Thank you!!